# Random Neo4j database location for Embedded Jersey Tests

Tags: multithreading, junit, jersey, neo4j, spring-data

I'm using *com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest* to create JUnit tests for my Jersey application. The application uses neo4j with Spring Data to load data and return it via the REST API.

The test starts an embedded grizzly server with my jersey neo4j spring data webapp. After that i'm able to invoke rest requests and create nodes in the neo4j database. 
Unfortunately my test is currently fixed to a single neo4j database location since this is configured within my *applicationContext.xml* like so:

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="/tmp/myapp/neo4jdb" />
```

My test would fail if i excute a similar test at the same time because the same directory would be used and only one neo4j can obtain the lock.

I know about the *SpringJUnit4ClassRunner* but i can't use it because i have already a neo4j instance running within my embedded server.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
```

The test should create an neo4j database in a random directory.

Questions:

- Is there any way to change the storeDirectory and clear to the neo4j database. Changing the storeDirectory in the setupOnce would help as well.
- Is there any way to clear the neo4j database. (I can't autowire in my test because it is not part of the spring context)

Comment: Is there a way to use spring container extension points, http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using a Java-based bean configuration:

```
package com.gentics.sandboxmanager.service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext;

@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.gentics.sandboxmanager.repository")
@Configuration
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    private static File databaseLocation;
    private static EmbeddedGraphDatabase neo4jDB;

    /**
     * Returns the neo4j database
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static EmbeddedGraphDatabase getNeo4jDatabase() {
        return neo4jDB;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService() throws IOException {

        // TODO use properties so that the app does not use a temp dir
        databaseLocation = Files.createTempDirectory("neo4j").toFile();
        databaseLocation.deleteOnExit();

        neo4jDB = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(databaseLocation.getAbsolutePath());
        return neo4jDB;
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
        return new Neo4jMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator() {
        return new Neo4jExceptionTranslator();
    }

}
```

Each JerseyTest testcase will restart the webapp. The neo4j will therefore always use an empty neo4j database.

Additonal links:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/setup.html#d0e3653